# phone as router, no internet needed.

Tags: wi-fi, router

So I have a droid RAZR Maxx HD xt926 and I currently use it without a Verizon sim or plan. I use it in airplane mode with wifi turned ON, so I can do Google voice calling and texting.

I would like to use the phones wifi networking capabilities to be a router for my friends and I when we are away so that we can do LAN parties. However when I install apps like HOTSPOT CONTROL and that Fifi one it just fails saying I have to have a data plan. I DONT NEED the internet access. All I want is a basic wireless switch/router.

I have also searched everywhere I can think for an app that will do this.

Phone is NOT ROOTED as many of you probably know this particular phone cannot be rooted or the bootloader unlocked because some genius at Motorola decided I can't do that.

Does anyone have an idea of something that will work?

Comment: So you're on firmware 18x.46 **.15**? As far as I know, anything below that can be unlocked and rooted easily, including **.10** which is also KitKat.

Comment: Here is a screenie: https://goo.gl/photos/NnKkFt5nwKCVmEih8

Comment: Check [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/droid-razr-m/general/root-droid-razr-m-xt907-183-46-15-t3030852) out - it's for RAZR M, but the two are nearly identical, they both got .15 that patched BL unlocking.

Comment: @AndyYan Phone is rooted! the link you posted, after a few hours of searching, led me to a different method that worked! Now back to the app thing: any apps I should try?

Comment: Also is there a way for this to be configured via command line? I am very familiar with the command line and scripting on Linux. I have been playing around on the terminal since I've had the root and it seems pretty familiar! I miss some of my utilities *cough* nano *cough* but I think I'm ready to take on the command line approach (if there is one.)

Comment: Also, the phone on the new firmware is like 100 times faster. No Joke. Where do I find changelogs for Motorola firmware? I would like to see what dope they did.

Comment: I don't have a clue to any of those... I've been using 3rd-party ROMs and their built-in hotspot never required data, so I've never used other apps for that purpose. You're now rooted but bootloader is still locked so no go on that.